# Data transformation- Compare two dataframes and split amount equally based on condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this:
df1:

```
Account     Product     aws_service             cost
NA-PRD      prod1       AmazonQuickSight        50
NA-PRD      prod1       s3                      70
NA-DEV      prod1       AmazonQuickSight        60
NA-DEV      prod1       kms                     20
NA-AD-HOC   prod1                 AWSELB        70
NA-AD-HOC   prod1              AmazonECS        100
```

df2:

```
Account      Product                cost
NA-PRD       prod1                  10
NA-DEV       prod1                  12
NA-AD-HOC    prod1                  20
```

I want to split the individual account's cost of df2 into df1 equally based on the number of aws_services for a particular Product
So Output will be:

```
Account     Product     aws_service             cost
NA-PRD      prod1       AmazonQuickSight        55
NA-PRD      prod1       s3                      75
NA-DEV      prod1       AmazonQuickSight        66
NA-DEV      prod1       kms                     26
NA-AD-HOC   prod1                 AWSELB        80
NA-AD-HOC   prod1              AmazonECS        110
```

For this case there is only one product in df1 and it has two different aws services so cost allocation was 50%-50%

How can I achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC simply divide the cost by `count` of product:

```
x = df.groupby("Account")["Product"].count()
y = df2.set_index("Account")["cost"]

df["cost"] += df["Account"].map(y/x)

print (df)

     Account Product       aws_service   cost
0     NA-PRD   prod1  AmazonQuickSight   55.0
1     NA-PRD   prod1                s3   75.0
2     NA-DEV   prod1  AmazonQuickSight   66.0
3     NA-DEV   prod1               kms   26.0
4  NA-AD-HOC   prod1            AWSELB   80.0
5  NA-AD-HOC   prod1         AmazonECS  110.0
```